# How to use RC4 key bytes in "C" to de-crypt a file using python

Tags: python, c

our team program encrypted a file using rc4 cipher, but it is in C programming Language

I want to convert it to Python

I have already search some solutions.

such as : Crypto.Cipher

But it must provide key string

I am looking back to original C code, it is only using key bytes, no string key

I don't understand the RC4 cipher

So, I want to know how to convert the key bytes to string key

or how to use these key bytes to decrypt file use python

```
const unsigned char key[256] = {
……more……
    168, 90, 198, 246, 86, 221, 
……more……
};

unsigned char s_box[SBOX_SIZE];

void rc4_ksa()
{
    int i , j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SBOX_SIZE; i++) {
        s_box[i] = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SBOX_SIZE; i++) {
        j = (j + s_box[i] + key[i % sizeof(key)]) % SBOX_SIZE;
        swap(&s_box[i], &s_box[j]);
    }
}

rc4_encrypt...
```

Comment: Your code snippet and problem context are not matching. Please elaborate in your code where is RC$ cipher. is it RC$ or RC4?

Comment: @Manmohan_singh  Sorry, I type wrong, it is RC4, not RC$. I update the code now

Comment: If I understood correctly your question, I think you want to use the `bytes` type in Python. If you have a string and want to convert it to bytes, use `encode`